# Width 100% with white borders around it. WHy?

Tags: html, css, image, width

Ok, I'm trying to design a website that has an image at the top that spans the full width of the browser. And below that I want to put different colored div containers that also span the full width. kinda like this:
http://hayden-demo.squarespace.com/

I've tried background-size:cover but I want different backgrounds for each section of the page.  The only thing I've found after many hours of searching is width: 100% but it leaves white borders around my image...
Please help, I'm desperate. This is my current CSS:

```
    .mainimg {
background-image: url(_DSC0656.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
width:100% !important;
height: 700px;
margin:0 auto;
display:block;
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `body`  element has some margins by default. Unless you remove them, any element that you put inside, no matter it's width (unless it's in position `absolute` I think) will have some borders. They aren't borders, but the gab in between the end of your element and the side of the body. Try this :

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}
```

If that doesn't work, then please show us an example of your code on JSBin, Codepen or similar (or even a live version if possible).

Comment: Have you tried that solution for yourself or are you just guessing margin issue ?

Comment: Oh wow that worked! can't believe I didn't think of this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @tchrikch I have had this problem many times before and this fixed it, and I'm doing the best I can with the code he provided. Looking at his existing code, it should work unless he didn't remove the margins on the body.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works as intended!

Answer (score 1):

did you tried to reset the margin and padding of all element to 0, if not then try following code into your css file.

```
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

Comment: I did yes to the html and div elements. But for some reason not to the body as Charles mentioned. Anyway thanks for the really quick reply!